# Saving SQL files into specific folders in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am using `Oracle 11g`. When I open a new SQL file writing the command

```
ed filename.sql
```

A new file is created in my `bin` folder with the name as `filename` but, I want them to be in separate folders for my convenience. I am developing 3 application(well for my practice only). I want them to store in different folders for each project. I tried all of the following none of them worked please tell me how can I save the files into specific folders.

```
ed erp/logindetails.sql
ed 'erp/logindetails.sql'
ed "erp/logindetails.sql"
ed 'erp\logindetails.sql'
ed erp\logindetails.sql
```

These commands except where I used `""` worked and opened the default text editor with the name `afiedt.buf` which I am getting when I enter only `edit`. No files are created with any of the above command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving [`EDIT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve021.htm) a relative path to the file; since your current working directory seems to be the `bin` directory that the SQL*Plus directory is in (is this Windows, and are you running a shortcut that sets the working directory, maybe?) it will try to create a file like `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\erp\logindetails.sql`, and you're unlikely to have created an `erp` directory there. Giving the full path to the directory will work:

```
edit c:\users\dibya\projects\erp\logindetails.sql
```

for example.

As noted in the documentation, `EDIT` will search for existing files, but that involves setting an environment variable - which you'd have to change as you move between the projects. You might find it easier to edit the files in the OS and just run them from SQL*Plus.

You might also be able to use separate shortcuts to launch SQL*Plus for each project, each setting the 'start in' directory to a project-specific location - then just `edit logindetails.sql` would be looking in the right place by default. Or, from a command prompt `cd` into the relevant project-specific directory and launch SQL*Plus from there, which is effectively what a shortcut would do.